# Java Gridbagconstraints gridy Issues

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I am trying to create a form and having difficulty with`GridBagConstraints`. When I set`gridy`it does not appear to be working. Here is my code:

```
thisWindow = new GridBagConstraints();
thisWindow.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
thisWindow.weightx = 1.0;
thisWindow.weighty = 1.0;
thisWindow.gridheight = 4;
thisWindow.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
//set elements
thisWindow.gridx = 0;
thisWindow.gridy = 0;
charScreen.add(nameLbl, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 1;
thisWindow.gridy = 0;
charScreen.add(charNameCmb, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 2;
thisWindow.gridy = 0;
charScreen.add(raceLbl, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 3;
thisWindow.gridy = 0;
charScreen.add(raceCmb, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 4;
thisWindow.gridy = 0;
charScreen.add(genderLbl, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 5;
thisWindow.gridy = 0;
charScreen.add(genderCmb, thisWindow);
//This should be on a new line.
thisWindow.gridx = 0;
thisWindow.gridy = 1;
charScreen.add(levelLbl, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 1;
thisWindow.gridy = 1;
charScreen.add(levelSpn, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 2;
thisWindow.gridy = 1;
charScreen.add(charClassLbl, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 3;
thisWindow.gridy = 1;
charScreen.add(charClassCmb, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 4;
thisWindow.gridy = 1;
charScreen.add(deityLbl, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 5;
thisWindow.gridy = 1;
charScreen.add(deityCmb, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 6;
thisWindow.gridy = 1;
charScreen.add(homelandLbl, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 7;
thisWindow.gridy = 1;
charScreen.add(homelandTxt, thisWindow);
//This should be on a third line.
thisWindow.gridx = 0;
thisWindow.gridy = 2;
charScreen.add(sizeLbl, thisWindow);
thisWindow.gridx = 1;
thisWindow.gridy = 2;
charScreen.add(sizeTxt, thisWindow);
charScreen.setVisible(true);
```

I've tried using various anchors and nothing helps. The issue I am having is that the two parts that should be on a second and third line are both overlapping the first line. Any advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The best way to get us to fully and quickly understand your problem would be if you were to to create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small but complete program that only has necessary code to demonstrate your problem, that we can copy, paste, compile and run without modification.

Answer (score 3):

Your gridHeight is messing you up.

Change:

```
thisWindow.gridheight = 4;
```

to

```
thisWindow.gridheight = 1;
```

Note that I created my own MCVE to test this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestCharScreen {

   private static GridBagConstraints thisWindow;
   private static JPanel charScreen = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
   private static JLabel nameLbl = new JLabel("nameLbl");
   private static JLabel charNameCmb = new JLabel("charNameCmb");
   private static JLabel raceLbl = new JLabel("raceLbl");
   private static JLabel raceCmb = new JLabel("raceCmb");
   private static JLabel genderLbl = new JLabel("genderLbl");
   private static JLabel genderCmb = new JLabel("genderCmb");
   private static JLabel levelLbl = new JLabel("levelLbl");
   private static JLabel levelSpn = new JLabel("levelSpn");
   private static JLabel charClassLbl = new JLabel("charClassLbl");
   private static JLabel charClassCmb = new JLabel("charClassCmb");
   private static JLabel deityLbl = new JLabel("deityLbl");
   private static JLabel deityCmb = new JLabel("deityCmb");
   private static JLabel homelandLbl = new JLabel("homelandLbl");
   private static JLabel homelandTxt = new JLabel("homelandTxt");
   private static JLabel sizeLbl = new JLabel("sizeLbl");
   private static JLabel sizeTxt = new JLabel("sizeTxt");


   public static void main(String[] args) {


      thisWindow = new GridBagConstraints();
      thisWindow.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
      thisWindow.weightx = 1.0;
      thisWindow.weighty = 1.0;

      // *****
      thisWindow.gridheight = 4;  // 4? *****

      thisWindow.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
      //set elements
      thisWindow.gridx = 0;
      thisWindow.gridy = 0;
      charScreen.add(nameLbl, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 1;
      thisWindow.gridy = 0;
      charScreen.add(charNameCmb, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 2;
      thisWindow.gridy = 0;
      charScreen.add(raceLbl, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 3;
      thisWindow.gridy = 0;
      charScreen.add(raceCmb, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 4;
      thisWindow.gridy = 0;
      charScreen.add(genderLbl, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 5;
      thisWindow.gridy = 0;
      charScreen.add(genderCmb, thisWindow);
      //This should be on a new line.
      thisWindow.gridx = 0;
      thisWindow.gridy = 1;
      charScreen.add(levelLbl , thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 1;
      thisWindow.gridy = 1;
      charScreen.add(levelSpn, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 2;
      thisWindow.gridy = 1;
      charScreen.add(charClassLbl, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 3;
      thisWindow.gridy = 1;
      charScreen.add(charClassCmb, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 4;
      thisWindow.gridy = 1;
      charScreen.add(deityLbl, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 5;
      thisWindow.gridy = 1;
      charScreen.add(deityCmb, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 6;
      thisWindow.gridy = 1;
      charScreen.add(homelandLbl, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 7;
      thisWindow.gridy = 1;
      charScreen.add(homelandTxt, thisWindow);
      //This should be on a third line.
      thisWindow.gridx = 0;
      thisWindow.gridy = 2;
      charScreen.add(sizeLbl, thisWindow);
      thisWindow.gridx = 1;
      thisWindow.gridy = 2;
      charScreen.add(sizeTxt, thisWindow);

      charScreen.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("charScreen"));
      // charScreen.setVisible(true);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(nameLbl, charScreen);
   }
}
```

Comment: @Ryan: note that I created my own MCVE to test this out. Please see code above. In the future, consider posting something like this. Note that I just used JLabels and no other components, since that was all that was needed to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: @Ryan Remember to accept the answer if you are happy with it